# Xna 4.0 Publishing Game

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, publishing

I have a problem publishing a game in XNA 4.0, Whenever I send the published files to my other computer which does not have XNA installed and I execute the Setup.exe it keeps giving me this error :

> Unable to install or run the application. The application requires
>   that assembly Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices Version 4.0.0.0 be
>   installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) first. Please contact
>   your system administrator.

I went searching on Google for solutions and read that people told me to remove the gamerservices reference from my whole project, so I did that and rebuilt my solution and published again, but unfortunately still the same error.

Ps: This is a clean project with 1 class

> Game.cs

Anybody that experienced this kind of error or can elaborate on this issue? Please feel free to post any help.

Comment: You need to install the XNA runtime on other machines. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20914

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I'm wondering is there a way to include the xna runtime with your game?